# Invoking a workflow activity from a code activity

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is there a way to call a custom made workflow activity from within a CodeActivity? I have created some helpful activities (like sending emails and then writing to a log) that I use in some non-code based workflow activities and am wondering how I can use these from within my CodeActivity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a NativeActivity instead of a CodeActivity. With the NativeActivity the execution context will allow you to schedule other child activities.